# kubectl does not work when I set HTTPS_PROXY

Tags: kubernetes, proxy

I have an  `on-premises k8s cluster` with **3 master nodes** and **2 worker nodes**.

Also to communicate with the **masters** **(** `kube-apiserver` **)** I have configured another server using `haproxy` as an `external-load-balancer` so that I can manage my cluster from this server ( external LB ) using `kubectl`.
Everything is working fine.

However, due to company policies, none of our servers should have direct access to the Internet and should use a **proxy** for this purpose.
But the problem is that when I set `HTTPS_PROXY` , `kubectl` no longer works on the `load-balancer-server`.

For example when I run `kubectl get po` , I get the following error after a while:

`Error from server (InternalError): an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from succeeding (get pods)`

Is there any way I can set up  `HTTPS_PROXY` without `kubectl` crashing?

** setting `NO_PROXY` environment variable does **not** work.

** The operating system of all machines (cluster nodes and load balancer) is **ubuntu 20.04** and kubernetes version is **v1.20.1**

---

**UPDATE**:

the output of `https_proxy=https://my_proxy:proxy_port kubectl get po --v=8`:

```
I0223 09:08:39.754640   13129 loader.go:372] Config loaded from file:  /root/.kube/config
I0223 09:08:39.757257   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:08:39.757308   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:08:39.757335   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:08:39.757351   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:08:39.981279   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 223 milliseconds
I0223 09:08:39.981386   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:08:39.981739   13129 request.go:959] Got a Retry-After 1s response for attempt 1 to https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:08:40.982325   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:08:40.982406   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:08:40.982426   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:08:40.982440   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:08:41.220799   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 238 milliseconds
I0223 09:08:41.220872   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:08:41.221043   13129 request.go:959] Got a Retry-After 1s response for attempt 2 to https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
[...]
I0223 09:08:52.154579   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:08:52.154702   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:08:52.154778   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:08:52.154886   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:08:52.367941   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 212 milliseconds
I0223 09:08:52.368029   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:08:52.368235   13129 request.go:1123] Response Body: 
I0223 09:08:52.368457   13129 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from succeeding
I0223 09:08:52.369797   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:08:52.369852   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:08:52.369869   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:08:52.369882   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:08:52.604917   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 234 milliseconds
I0223 09:08:52.604982   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:08:52.605130   13129 request.go:959] Got a Retry-After 1s response for attempt 1 to https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:08:53.605952   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:08:53.606046   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:08:53.606077   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:08:53.606099   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:08:53.840254   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 234 milliseconds
I0223 09:08:53.840424   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:08:53.840677   13129 request.go:959] Got a Retry-After 1s response for attempt 2 to https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
[...]
I0223 09:09:02.465448   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:02.465547   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:09:02.465631   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:09:02.465658   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:09:02.714359   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 248 milliseconds
I0223 09:09:02.714428   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:09:02.714533   13129 request.go:959] Got a Retry-After 1s response for attempt 9 to https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:03.715023   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:03.715118   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:09:03.715151   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:09:03.715177   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:09:04.013169   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 297 milliseconds
I0223 09:09:04.013342   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:09:04.013517   13129 request.go:959] Got a Retry-After 1s response for attempt 10 to https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:05.014802   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:05.014900   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:09:05.014938   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:09:05.014965   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:09:05.227157   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 212 milliseconds
I0223 09:09:05.227251   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:09:05.227355   13129 request.go:1123] Response Body: 
I0223 09:09:05.227446   13129 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from succeeding
I0223 09:09:05.227467   13129 shortcut.go:89] Error loading discovery information: an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from succeeding
I0223 09:09:05.227827   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:05.227855   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:09:05.227870   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:09:05.227922   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:09:05.471795   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 243 milliseconds
I0223 09:09:05.471894   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:09:05.472008   13129 request.go:959] Got a Retry-After 1s response for attempt 1 to https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
[...]
I0223 09:09:16.740190   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:16.740256   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:09:16.740273   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:09:16.740287   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:09:16.951744   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 211 milliseconds
I0223 09:09:16.951809   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:09:16.951923   13129 request.go:959] Got a Retry-After 1s response for attempt 10 to https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:17.952375   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:17.952438   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:09:17.952456   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:09:17.952469   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:09:18.247704   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 295 milliseconds
I0223 09:09:18.247818   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:09:18.247950   13129 request.go:1123] Response Body: 
I0223 09:09:18.248052   13129 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from succeeding
I0223 09:09:18.248369   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:18.248418   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:09:18.248437   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:09:18.248455   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:09:18.512174   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 263 milliseconds
I0223 09:09:18.512297   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:09:18.512494   13129 request.go:959] Got a Retry-After 1s response for attempt 1 to https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
[...]
I0223 09:09:29.443748   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:29.443818   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:09:29.443837   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:09:29.443852   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:09:29.679354   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 235 milliseconds
I0223 09:09:29.679447   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:09:29.679653   13129 request.go:959] Got a Retry-After 1s response for attempt 10 to https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:30.681025   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:30.681126   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:09:30.681161   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:09:30.681187   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:09:30.886073   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 204 milliseconds
I0223 09:09:30.886140   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:09:30.886268   13129 request.go:1123] Response Body: 
I0223 09:09:30.886359   13129 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from succeeding
I0223 09:09:30.886597   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:30.886621   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:09:30.886636   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:09:30.886650   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:09:31.104634   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 217 milliseconds
I0223 09:09:31.104767   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:09:31.105072   13129 request.go:959] Got a Retry-After 1s response for attempt 1 to https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
[...]
I0223 09:09:42.025403   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:42.025508   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:09:42.025527   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:09:42.025567   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:09:42.247663   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 222 milliseconds
I0223 09:09:42.247785   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:09:42.247975   13129 request.go:959] Got a Retry-After 1s response for attempt 10 to https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:43.249860   13129 round_trippers.go:432] GET https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383/api?timeout=32s
I0223 09:09:43.249943   13129 round_trippers.go:438] Request Headers:
I0223 09:09:43.249962   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0223 09:09:43.249976   13129 round_trippers.go:442]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.21.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/ca643a4
I0223 09:09:43.463941   13129 round_trippers.go:457] Response Status:  in 213 milliseconds
I0223 09:09:43.464007   13129 round_trippers.go:460] Response Headers:
I0223 09:09:43.464161   13129 request.go:1123] Response Body: 
I0223 09:09:43.464360   13129 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from succeeding
I0223 09:09:43.464885   13129 helpers.go:216] server response object: [{
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "an error on the server (\"\") has prevented the request from succeeding",
  "reason": "InternalError",
  "details": {
    "causes": [
      {
        "reason": "UnexpectedServerResponse"
      }
    ],
    "retryAfterSeconds": 1
  },
  "code": 500
}]
F0223 09:09:43.465021   13129 helpers.go:115] Error from server (InternalError): an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from succeeding
goroutine 1 [running]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2.stacks(0xc00000e001, 0xc0008693b0, 0x97, 0xe8)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:1021 +0xb9
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).output(0x3055420, 0xc000000003, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0005b0000, 0x25f2cf0, 0xa, 0x73, 0x40e300)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:970 +0x191
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).printDepth(0x3055420, 0xc000000003, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2, 0xc0008e6d50, 0x1, 0x1)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:733 +0x16f
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2.FatalDepth(...)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:1495
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util.fatal(0xc00016ca80, 0x68, 0x1)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util/helpers.go:93 +0x288
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util.checkErr(0x207b2e0, 0xc000852a00, 0x1f07e88)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util/helpers.go:188 +0x935
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util.CheckErr(...)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util/helpers.go:115
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/get.NewCmdGet.func1(0xc0000f62c0, 0xc00042d740, 0x1, 0x2)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/get/get.go:167 +0x159
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc0000f62c0, 0xc00042d720, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc0000f62c0, 0xc00042d720)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:854 +0x2c2
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc00044b340, 0xc000116120, 0xc00003a080, 0x4)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:958 +0x375
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:895
main.main()
    _output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubectl/kubectl.go:49 +0x21d

goroutine 4 [chan receive]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).flushDaemon(0x3055420)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:1164 +0x8b
created by k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2.init.0
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:418 +0xdf

goroutine 7 [select]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil(0x1f07da8, 0x207b5e0, 0xc00007cbd0, 0x1, 0xc00007ab40)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:167 +0x118
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil(0x1f07da8, 0x12a05f200, 0x0, 0x1, 0xc00007ab40)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:133 +0x98
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.Until(0x1f07da8, 0x12a05f200, 0xc00007ab40)
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:90 +0x4d
created by k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/util/logs.InitLogs
    /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/util/logs/logs.go:51 +0x96
```

Comment: "Is there any way I can set up HTTPS_PROXY without kubectl crashing" - are there any logs? How is it crashing?

Comment: @RadekW By "crashing"  I meant that I could no longer use `kubectl` and when I run the commands (`kubectl get po` for example) I get the following error after a while:
`Error from server (InternalError): an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from succeeding (get pods)`

Comment: Which kube-apiserver endpoint is triggered by your kubectl client? You can check it using a command: `https_proxy=https://your_server:9000 kubectl get po --v=8` Show me output from this command

Comment: @RadekW I updated the question. Do you mean `https_proxy=https://proxy_server:proxy_port kubectl get po --v=8`?
If not, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I meant proxy server. Thanks for answer. Could you check a direct connection to API Server using curl? `curl --proxy "http://your_company_proxy_server:proxy_port" "https://lb.kube.hesmoh.org:8383" -k` You should get an error 403 - Access Forbiden. Does your proxy server needs authentication? And please sanitize your sensitive data with posted commands' output, like internal DNS name of the APIServer address, we don't need it.

Comment: ** all the addresses are unreal. Yes I got 403:

{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 403
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242326/discussion-between-hesmoh-and-radekw).

Answer (score 0):

though too late, in case someone faces the similar issue
use the command below to fix this issue

export no_proxy=$no_proxy,(control plane IP)

e.g export no_proxy=$no_proxy, 10.0.0.1